# Why does my logo look terrible and blurry on Instagram and Facebook?

Tags: inkscape, logo

I am not a graphic designer at all. The first logo I made was in Photoshop for my Etsy store. Now I want to move off Etsy but can't make my own website until I have good quality graphics.

So I made the logo as a vector in Inkscape.

It looks fine but as soon as I set it as my Instagram logo or anything, it looks super blurry and awful. I have tried different formats and making it the size px instagram requires, but it always comes out looking the same.

I've attached the png and also a screen shot of how it looks on Instagram.

[image: instagram logo]
[image: png logo]

Comment: Have you tried setting your background in a different color? This is relevant: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21204/why-do-jpeg-files-blur-red-more-than-other-colors

Comment: How zoomed in are you? The closer you are the more pixelated the logo will be. Additionally Instagram *might* be compressing it further after you upload it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook: Ways to preserve image quality of uploaded images?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3134/facebook-ways-to-preserve-image-quality-of-uploaded-images)

Answer (score 4):

The example you posted has artefacts caused by Instagram rescaling, and adding excessive jpeg compression to the image.  The only way to solve this is to rescale and export as jpeg yourself, so that Instagram doesn't have to.  If you take control of resizing and turning it into a jpeg, the result should be much better.

Instagram and other social networking sites like Facebook are notorious for applying excessive compression to images.

An Instagram logo should be 110px x 110px.

- Open your original big image in Photoshop or GIMP, or similar raster
  image editor.
- Scale the image to 110px x 110px
- Export as jpeg, with quality setting high (around 60%)
- The file size should be a little less than 5kb
- Now upload the resized image to Instagram

This is what it should look like.  Don't be tempted to zoom in or it will look blurry/pixelated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your artwork looks sharp at 1000 x 1000 px which should be more than enough.

Your screenshot is pixelated like it has been scaled up about four times.

I'm guessing that your browser is zoomed in. Try to check if the zoom level is 100%.

Answer (score 1):

I see two things that may be in play here:

[The red color is notorious for compressing badly.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21204/why-do-jpeg-files-blur-red-more-than-other-colors)

Another thing to consider, is that social media tends to have a limit to the size of image you can upload. When you go above that, compression kicks in.

[This](https://www.wimarys.com/quality-photo-export-instagram/) suggests for Instagram that pixel size is relevant but also file size in MB.

> because their compression algorithm will kick in when your image size
>   exceeds 1.6MB and 1080px.

And for [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/266520536764594?helpref=related)

> Regular photos: 720px, 960px or 2048px wide 
>   Cover photos: 851px by 315px
>   To avoid compression when you upload your cover photo, make sure
>   the file size is less than 100KB Save your image as a JPEG with an
>   sRGB color profile

Comment: Thanks Emilie 
I tried many different versions testing with the correct px and MB sizes and jpeg with sRGB but they all ended up looking more or less the same - bad! 
I believe the problem is with the flat red colour. Thanks for bringing this to my attention.

Answer (score 0):

As Emilie said, there are special sizes for each social media.

[image: Instagram]

If your logo size is 1000 X 1000 px and Instagram Profile photo size is 110 X 110 px, who knows what Instagram does with the other 890 px.

At this link, a big list of each [Media Image sizes](https://louisem.com/2852/social-media-cheat-sheet-sizes).

**Possible solution**

Instagram is an application about pictures, this means images with a sequence of halftones. Your logo has flat colors areas. See the difference between putting your logo as a profile image on Instagram and Behance:

**Instagram**:

[image: Instagram]

**Behance**:

[image]

It is clear that in Behance the image is sharper, it does not produce the known as "photoshop artifact".

If Instagram produce Photoshop Artifact in big flat colors areas, avoid them. This is your logo as profile image in Instagram with a background pattern instead the flat red:

[image: background]

And this is the uploaded image:

[image: bear]

Comment: Thanks Danielillo, 
I tried with 110x110 px but it was still the same.
I will change the background from the flat red to a textured background.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My experiments showed that when using the browser version, none of the suggestions on how to make instagram not recompress your files works. However, adding some texture to the logo makes the compression artifacts inconceivable.

Answer (score -2):

A quick generic tip is to export images at 100 dpi, the standard is 72 dpi for screen related artwork and it doesn't seem like a biggie but does make things pop more.

Comment: how does exporting images at 100dpi "makes images pop more"? a 110x110px image will have the same amount of pixels no matter how many DPI.

Comment: standard screen dpi is 72 - make an image at 1000x1000 make 2 copies, scale one to 100x100 @ 72 dpi then do the same to the other but 100x100 @ 100 dpi and compare the images side by side. This mimics the process most people use along with using "save for the web" type options that don't let you set the dpi.

Comment: This does not work because a 110x110px image exactly the same regardless of the DPI setting. DPI is not a measure of quality, it's only the output resolution (i.e. the print resolution). The DPI/PPI setting is completely ignored by browsers. You need to read this: [The Myth of DPI](http://www.rideau-info.com/photos/mythdpi.html)

Answer (score -3):

just save your image as png 150dpi and upload.

Comment: Welcome! And why does it solve the  given issue? Please explain better!