# Instagram profile image problems - noise suggestions?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop

So I am trying to upload this logo - [image]

Have tried from 110x110 72dpi all the way through to 12000x12000 150dpi jpeg and png. All look awful!

After doing a bit of research think it may be because of the red, I have already tried just adding some noise but it has completely changed the image when I upload to instagram. I feel like that is somewhat a good sign as it definitely makes a difference but I'm look for suggestions about the kind of noise I should be using or what settings when I apply the filter.

[image: 1. with added noise]
 [image: 2. how noise looks on instagram]

Comment: Danielillo offers "noise suggestions" here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/110602/126327 - looking at other dupes, assuming you don't want "noise" to be the only choice there's gradient and something that appears to be red leather.

Comment: What are the color space and bit depth of the original?

Comment: As a quick test, I uploaded your image to a dummy Instagram account I have. It looked fine. I deleted the image immediately, but I have a screenshot if you would like to see. There was no noise visible as you saw there, so there is not a problem with the specific red you're using.