# Creating high quality text over solid backgraound image

Tags: text, microsoft-powerpoint

I'm trying to make post for an Instagram account, posts are simple, just some texts over simple one color solid background but, the problem is that the quality isn't well enough and writings are not clear enough and especially around alphabets are not sharp enough and make the picture blurry and hard to read and the problem even gets worse in smaller screens. for example
[image: an example of problem]

right now I'm using Powerpoint for creating the posts and i tried fixing the problem by increasing the output image dpi, it sort of made it better especially in bigger screens but still the result is not satisfactory. I want to know
what cause the problem and what can i do to be able create sharper pictures? Can possibly using designated apps like Photoshop improve the result? I prefer Powerpoint because it just easier to use, all i need to do is filling the text in a predefined template.Please if you know other apps for windows that are easy to work with and improve the result please recommend.

also any tips on background and font color that could improve the image quality will be much appreciated, I have tried some different colors and it seems to me some color combination make the problem less obvious.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Does this answer your question? [Why does my logo look terrible and blurry on Instagram and Facebook?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/110596/why-does-my-logo-look-terrible-and-blurry-on-instagram-and-facebook). Using higher resolution images is not the solution, it also has nothing to do with the software you are using. The problem is with social media sites and how they process and compress images to keep file sizes small. [also see here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3134/facebook-ways-to-preserve-image-quality-of-uploaded-images)

Comment: @BillyKerr OK, thanks. It is helpful.