# Instagram blurrying my designed posts

Tags: adobe-indesign, export, image-quality, compression

I have some graphic design stuff to post on Instagram but no matter what I try, the image comes out blurry. I'd started with a file size of 1080x1080px when making in (currently using InDesign). I tried many export formats (JPEG and PNG in multiple different resolutions/ppis and quality). I even tried exporting to PDF and converting to JPEG but no luck. I've browsed some of the questions on here but I wasn't able to find a solution that worked for my problem. Can anyone help me?

Original image: [image]

Screenshots from Instagram (they look a lot worse on my phone btw): [image]

[image]

Comment: Related: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21204/why-do-jpeg-files-blur-red-more-than-other-colors

Comment: It is more likely to be compression rather than blur. Not much that you can do as sites like instagram do convert all your uploaded images and compress them so they load faster. Also. in Indesign or pdf it will look a lot sharper as they use vector fonts. Two things to look out for to get the best quality are: use recommended image dimensions and export as jpg in highest quality. (I assume you done both of them already)

Comment: I did. Well, guess I'll just have to deal with it! haha. thanks for your input.

Comment: Image size is too big for instagram, which will cause instagram to automatically resample and add compression to the image, which causes the problem you are seeing. The image should  be 1080 x 1080px, then export as JPEG using a proper image editor, and set the compression to a reasonable level. Then post on instagram.

Comment: Could be a minor mistake when posting here, or you are saying you *also* tried 1080x1080, but the original image you posted is 1800x1800, not 1080x1080 that you stated in the question.

Comment: @Billy Kerr I do not think that is how it works. As far as I know most social media platforms recommend to upload jpgs at highest quality, as they are compressed anyway (they are also sized to different formats so images have to be generated anyway). As you may know if you have a jpg with low compression and you save it again at the same compression level, the quality will get worse due to the way jpg compression works...

Comment: @JulianSteinmann if you upload an image larger than the optimum size in pixels or in file size, the image will be resampled and recompressed making everything worse. You can sometimes avoid that by doing the resizing and adding compression yourself first, by using proper image editing software. If the image is the right size, then the social media platform won't need to do anything to it.

Answer (score 3):

You literally need to deal with it, as it is, and there's some guidance on this, here: https://www.adobe.com/express/discover/sizes/instagram.

Instagram and pretty much every social media app, will process photos & videos based on whatever sizing/cropping/compression/etc rules they've built into the app at that particular moment. Not just your photos, everybody's photos.

Then, they could update the image rules with every new update of the app.

Answer (score 1):

**Not really an answer to the question but interesting in this context:*

I was wondering if @Billy Kerr could be right and highly compressed images wont be re-saved and compressed further. Would have surprised me if that would have been the case. But the result is even more surprising than this.

Just tried:

Left before upload: 1080x1080px img compressed at worst quality in photoshop is 32kb.

Right After upload: Now only 14kb size? How is that even possible? They must have some insane compression algorithm or does photoshop add something else to the file that insta removes?

[image]

Comment: I give up, just tried something similar. Made a perfectly sized image 1080 x 1080px for an insta post, added moderate compression, around 70% quality, saved as jpeg, file size 71kb, looks pretty decent, no artifacts or blurring  to speak of.  On upload to instagram, the jpeg artifacts and blurring are horrible.  Then I tried with a PNG, which has no compression at all,  and the result is the same - horrible artifacts and blurring. Looks like there's nothing that will really fix this at all, unless instagram stops recompressing already compressed images.

Comment: I also used red and blue in the graphic, which seems to be the worst possible combination for causing the problem.

Comment: +1 BTW for proving me wrong ;)

Comment: @BillyKerr red and bright green too. Like a red shape with green thick stroke.

Comment: You guys know they update the app every month :) Whatever seems to be working today, will likely be different in the next update.

Comment: @Lucian, yeah that might explain it.